New Customer Email Template do not change
I have a weird issue! When I create a new Email Template for a New customer (before the account is confirmed) and a new customer after it is confirmed. The template does not change.
I have set the email in: store - configuration - customer - customer configuration.
The New customer after confirmation looks like it is a custom template as it is in Norwegian ETC, But the other one is in English and does not change even if i create the template directly in Norwwgian. Anyone know what the issue can be.
Magneto 2.4.3. - Porto Theme - Sending email through Mailchimp/Mandril.

What steps you try to email template on magento?

Go to Marketing - Communocations - Email template. New template. Then I choose a template, in this case, Porto New customer., Amend it so it is correct for my store. Then i go to Store, configuration - choose website - Customer  - Customer configuration. Then i choose the template in the drop down. Save Clear  cache,

Have you try to set the same template into default configuration instead of Website Specific?

Yes i have tried that,

Have you check by magento default theme? if you use third party theme.

What do you mean? Not sure if I follow you

After some troubleshooting, I found out that was another 3rd party module that was overwriting these emails.

So, just to make sure: the problem is solved now?

yes it is, was a 3rd party module we where not know about
